# Ruby Dump all cron jobs to text file

Tags: ruby, cron

I want a ruby script that will dump all the existing cron jobs to a text file using `"crontab -l"` or anything else that will achieve the same objective. Also the text file should be possible to use with `crontab txtfile` to create the cron jobs again.

Below is the code I already wrote:

```
def dump_pre_cron_jobs(file_path)
        begin
            cron_list = %x[crontab -l]
            if(cron_list.size > 0)
                cron_list.each do |crl|
                    mymethod_that_writes_tofile(file_path, crl) unless crl.chomp.include?("myfilter")
                end
            end
        rescue Exception => e
            raise(e.message)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Have you written such a script or at least started it, and ran into problems? Or did you just want to throw out that idea hoping someone would write it for you? Is this a job assignment or an itch you personally want to scratch?

Comment: Already wrote one but since am fairly new to ruby, want to get experts contribution. Here it is: `def dump_pre_cron_jobs(file_path)
  begin   
   cron_list = %x[crontab -l]
   if(cron_list.size > 0)
    cron_list.each do |crl|
     mymethod_that_writes_to_file(file_path, crl)
    end
   end
  rescue Exception => e
   raise(e.message)
  end
 end`

Comment: Thanks, but putting it in a comment doesn't do much good because it makes it unreadable. Append it to your question by editing it. If you indent the code four spaces Stack Overflow will automatically format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Why does this need to be a Ruby script?

As you say, you can dump the crontab to a file with `crontab -l > crontab.txt`.

To read them back in again, simply use `crontab crontab.txt`, or `cat crontab.txt | crontab -`

Comment: Because this part of ruby application creating new cron jobs but needs to capture the existing ones first otherwise they will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Vortura that you do not need to create a Ruby script to do this.

If you really want to, here is a probable way:

```rb
File.open('crontab.txt', 'w') do |crontab|
  crontab << `crontab -l`
end
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Running this as root, or using `sudo` should capture all the cron jobs on a system, not just a single users' jobs. Run it as yourself or as that user and it might capture just those jobs. I haven't test that aspect of it.

---

Trying to run `crontab -l` to capture crontab files for all the users and packages seems the indirect way to do the task and could have the hassle of dealing with password requests hanging your code. I'd write code to comb through the directories that store them, rather than mess with prompts. Run the code using `sudo` and you shouldn't have any problems accessing the files.

Take a look at the discussion at: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/etc-crontab-vs-etc-cron-d-vs-var-spool-cron-crontabs-853881/ for information on where the actual cron tab files are stored on disk.

Also https://superuser.com/questions/389116/how-to-recover-crontab-jobs-from-filesystem/389137 has similar information.

Mac OS varies a little from Linux in where Apple puts the cron files. Run `man cron` at the command-line for the definitive details on either OS.

---

Here's slightly-tested code for how I'd back up the files. How you restore them is for you to figure out, but it shouldn't be hard to figure out:

```
require 'fileutils'

BACKUP_PATH = '/path/to/some/safe/storage/directory'

CRONTAB_DIRS = %w[
  /usr/lib/cron/tabs
  /var/spool/cron
  /etc/anacrontab
  /etc/cron.d
]

CRONTAB_FILES = %w[
  /etc/cron_list
]

def dump_pre_cron_jobs(file_path)

  full_backup_path = File.join(
    BACKUP_PATH,
    File.dirname(file_path)
  )
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(full_backup_path) unless Dir.exist?(full_backup_path)

  File.write(
    File.join(
      full_backup_path,
      file_path
    ),
    File.read(file_path)
  )
rescue Exception => e
  STDERR.puts e.message
end

CRONTAB_DIRS.each do |ct|
  next unless Dir.exist?(ct)
  begin
    Dir.entries(File.join(ct, '*')).each { |fn| dump_pre_cron_jobs(fn) }
  rescue Errno::EACCES => e
    STDERR.puts e.message
  end
end

CRONTAB_FILES.each do |fn|
  dump_pre_cron_jobs(fn)
end
```

You'll need to run this as root via `sudo` to access the directories and files as they're usually locked down from unauthorized prying eyes.

The code creates a repository of crontabs, in `BACKUP_PATH`, based on their original file paths. No changes are made to the file contents so they can be restored as-is by copying them back via `cp` or writing code to reverse this process.

Comment: This is assuming you want to get cron jobs for all users? What of if it's just cron jobs for the current logged on user? Would my script be ok?

Comment: Well, you did say "all the existing cron jobs", not "a single user's existing cron jobs", but, run it as yourself and it might capture just you because of the way permissions work.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake on my part meant for the logged on user as the app will be deployed by a specific user. Will test your script and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @the Tin Man, just testing your code but getting error: `undefined method `exist?' for Dir:Class` at position `next unless Dir.exist?(ct)`.

Comment: [`Dir.exist?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html) is correct. If your version of Ruby is ancient try `Dir.exists?` instead. You can use `File.exist?` or `File.exists?` too. They test both files and directories. Ruby 1.9+ has `Dir.exist?`

Comment: Now getting error: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - No such directory` on line: `Dir.entries(File.join(ct, '*')).each { |fn| dump_pre_cron_jobs(fn) }`